# ALLOWED_HOSTS is set, but Django is still giving a 500 error when DEBUG=False

Tags: django

In Django 1.5, ALLOWED_HOSTS became a required setting for when DEBUG=False.  However, in my app, I have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mycompany.com']`, and I'm hitting the app via a "http://mysubdomain.mycompany.com" URL, but Django is still giving a 500 error/response.

With DEBUG=True, everything works fine, so it appears that Django is just ignoring that setting.  Is there something else that could cause Django to bork out when DEBUG=False?

Is there a way to make Django spit out some details, in the log, about what its problem is?  By default, it just spits out something like the following in the log:

```
at=info method=GET path="/admin/login/?next=/admin/" host=mysubdomain.mycompany.com request_id=69e99b68-5b57-4f3f-a10d-898deb507ae4 fwd="123.456.789.101" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=161ms status=500 bytes=253
```

which is no help at all...

Comment: Is it not supposed to be *.mycompany.com instead (with the asterisk)? Otherwise, the Allowed Host is a list, so manually add in all the list of domains (in full) that you want to allow.

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#s-allowed-hosts) it should not have an asterisk.

Comment: According to the documentation, it should not have asterisk as in catching every single host, in which it states: "you are responsible to provide your own validation of the Host header", however in your case, you want it to catch everything subdomain of the main domain mycompany.com, right?

Comment: If the domain didn't match, it would return a 400, not a 500, so that's not the problem. The current setting is fine. What makes you think it's related to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`? I'd set up more detailed logging to capture at least the exception message.

Comment: @Troy At this point, I'll recommend you don't ignore any third party application you're using. If you're using Django Compress to compress your css/js imports, make sure you have this line in your settings: COMPRESS_ENABLED = os.environ.get('COMPRESS_ENABLED', False) | See here: http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/